# How to make a UIViewRepresentable @ViewBuilder work with dynamic content?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

Is it possible to make a `UIViewRepresentable` view which takes a `ViewBuilder` argument work with dynamic content such as `ForEach` loops?

I have the following `UIViewRepresentable` view which I’m using to drop down to `UIKit` and get some custom `UIScrollView` behaviour:

```swift
struct CustomScrollView<Content:View>: UIViewRepresentable {

    private let content: UIView
    private let scrollView = CustomUIScrollView()

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = UIHostingController(rootView: content()).view
        self.content.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        scrollView.addSubview(content)
        // ...
        return scrollView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}

}
```

This works fine with static content as follows:

```swift
var body: some View {
    CustomScrollView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1..<50) { number in
                Text(String(number))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails with dynamic content, showing a blank view:

```swift
var body: some View {
    CustomScrollView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.numbers) { number in
                Text(String(number))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that this is because when `makeUIView()` is called my dynamic data is empty, and it is later filled or updated. I evaluate my `UIViewRepresentable`’s `content` at init, and don’t update it in `updateUIView()`.

---

How do you go about updating dynamic child content in `updateUIView()`? I tried capturing the `@ViewBuilder` parameter as an `@escaping` closure and evaluating it every time `updateUIView()` is called, which seems like the right solution (albeit inefficient?), but no luck so far.

Comment: You should see this https://github.com/Onaeem26/SwiftyUIScrollView. In here you could see how to handle dynamic content via 'update'.

Comment: There's a memory leak, scrollView should be init in makeUIView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluation of @ViewBuilder fails because you mutating the wrong copy of the struct here

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
```

You should mutate `uiView`'s subviews directly with the `content()`

Updated Answer: Removed solution with a coordinator, because in some cases it works not as expected

Comment: But how to solve this without a coordinator?

Answer (score 2):

The following might be helpful. It is not clear how absent `CustomUIScrollView` behaves (probably the issue is there), but using standard `UIScrollView` works with dynamic ForEach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct CustomScrollView<Content:View>: UIViewRepresentable {

    private let content: UIView
    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = UIHostingController(rootView: content()).view
        self.content.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(content)
        let constraints = [
            content.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            content.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
        ]
        scrollView.addConstraints(constraints)
        return scrollView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}

}

struct TestCustomScrollView: View {
    private var items = Array(repeating: "Test", count: 50)
    var body: some View {
        CustomScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.0) { i, item in
                    Text("\(item) - \(i)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `\.0`? I get a range exception.